# Xcode error Extra info about plist: ACL=<not found>

Tags: ios, xcode

Suddenly app not installing. Please help i tried lot of things.

here is my error message

> Details
>
> This app could not be installed at this time. Domain:
>   IXUserPresentableErrorDomain Code: 1 Failure Reason: Could not install
>   at this time. Recovery Suggestion: Failed to load Info.plist from
>   bundle at path
>   /Users/t-tech/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/927777E8-7512-4F60-A44D-4EE52D8DF817/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.4c0WJE/extracted/Kings
>   Portal.app/Frameworks/PINOperation.framework; Extra info about plist:
>   ACL= 
>   -- Failed to load Info.plist from bundle at path /Users/t-tech/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/927777E8-7512-4F60-A44D-4EE52D8DF817/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.4c0WJE/extracted/Kings
>   Portal.app/Frameworks/PINOperation.framework; Extra info about plist:
>   ACL=  Domain: MIInstallerErrorDomain Code: 35 User Info: {
>       FunctionName = "-[MIBundle _validateWithError:]";
>       LegacyErrorString = PackageInspectionFailed;
>       SourceFileLine = 128; }

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: your Info.plist file is missing on app folder ?

Comment: File is there..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After do this steps now working fine.

> 1. In terminal, remove the current cocoapods using: `sudo gem uninstall cocoapods`
> 2. Install the latest cocoapod version: `sudo gem install cocoapods`
> 3. Change directory to your project, then
> 4. `pod deintegrate`
> 5. `pod install`
> 6. Clean build (`Shift`+`Command`+K )
> 7. Rebuild the project in Xcode.

Comment: Nothing else worked for me, inbcluding reinstalling downgrading and upgrading Xcode, clearing everything possible on the device/simulator ... workspace, even updating cocoapods... then this finally worked, uninstalling the gem was the key in my case.