# This app could not be installed at this time. Extra info about plist: ACL=<not found>

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode11.3

Hi i am facing a issue while installing application i have tried different possible solution like.

1- uninstalling and reinstalling cocoapods
2- de-integrating pod
3- re-installing xcode

```
This app could not be installed at this time.
Domain: IXUserPresentableErrorDomain
Code: 1
Failure Reason: Could not install at this time.
Recovery Suggestion: Failed to load Info.plist from bundle at path /Users/mac-book/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/8BA55A81-1C17-463D-A957-6E4604DB3CA3/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.pcRxJr/extracted/Payload/TEST.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework; Extra info about plist: ACL=<not found>
```

Tried all solution suggested in this question as well 
[Xcode error Extra info about plist: ACL=<not found>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59944763/xcode-error-extra-info-about-plist-acl-not-found)

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '11.0'
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

target 'Darewro' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Darewro

  pod 'Alamofire', :git => 'https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire.git', :branch => 'alamofire5'
  pod 'PromisedFuture'
  pod 'XLPagerTabStrip', '~> 8.1'
  pod 'CountdownLabel', '>= 4.0'

  pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
#  pod 'Firebase/Auth'
  pod 'Firebase/Firestore'

  pod 'GoogleMaps'
  pod 'GooglePlaces'
  pod 'LGSideMenuController'
  pod 'paper-onboarding'
  pod 'RangeSeekSlider'
  pod 'SDWebImage'
  pod 'RealmSwift'
  pod 'MXParallaxHeader'
  pod 'Cosmos'
  pod 'SVProgressHUD'
  pod 'LGButton'
  pod 'AnyFormatKit'
  pod 'MXSegmentedPager'

end
```

Need help from developer community.

Comment: it compiles ok? and when and where does the error show when you try running it on a simulator? try cleaning your project and deleting DerivedData folder.

Comment: yes compiles while installing app on simulator it throws error

Comment: have tried all these things but in vein

Comment: post your Podfile. are you using a free or paid Apple developer account?

Comment: added the podfile. i'm using paid apple account

Comment: have you tried resetting the iOS Simulator? or try a different one? does this work on real devices?

Comment: yes i have cleared simulator data & it also dont install on real device

Comment: have you tried using a released version of Alamofire? ```pod 'Alamofire', '5.0.2'```