# Xcode 12, SwiftUI and Spotify.framework — Error: extra info about plist: ACL=<not found>

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui, spotify

I've been following these two links to install the Spotify.framework file in my new Xcode 12, SwiftUI project:

- https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/ios/
- https://github.com/spotify/ios-sdk#tutorial

I have the bridging header set up, I'm able to access the Spotify framework's classes inside of my `ContentView` but when I build and run, I get this error.

`This app could not be installed at this time.`

`Could not install at this time. Failed to load Info.plist from bundle at path /Users/zackshapiro/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/8E9DA6E5-925E-4C51-8D61-C8B345BF636A/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.9k9kTR/extracted/bars.app/Frameworks/SpotifyiOS.framework; Extra info about plist: ACL=<not found>`

Any ideas on how to fix this and get it running?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you added SpotifyiOS.framework to your project, have you added and selected as "Embed & Sign" as below:

[image]

If yes, try changing it to "Do Not Embed" as below and try :

[image]

If this doesn't work then try this solution proposed:
[Xcode error Extra info about plist: ACL=<not found>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59944763/xcode-error-extra-info-about-plist-acl-not-found)

Comment: That did it! Thanks Nandish!