# Xcode fails to install my app on both simulator and iPhone

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am trying to run my app on simulator/my phone but I get the following message. I had this problem on Xcode 12.2 too but after updating Xcode to 12.3 the problem didn't resolve. Changing library embed type to do not embed or having copy files to copy when installing gets the app to run but it crashes shortly since it can not load the library it self.

I have tried cleaning project and derived data folder, restarting my Mac, simulator (also reseting simulator data) and my phone.
Deleting the app and reinstalling frameworks with Carthage didn't help either
I am using latest Carthage version.

I have seen these following answers but were either unhelpful or about cocoapods:

[Xcode error Extra info about plist: ACL=<not found>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59944763/xcode-error-extra-info-about-plist-acl-not-found)

[Failed to load Info.plist from bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40327935/failed-to-load-info-plist-from-bundle)

```
Unable To Install “AppName”
Domain: IXUserPresentableErrorDomain
Code: 1
Failure Reason: Please try again later.
Recovery Suggestion: Failed to load Info.plist from bundle at path /Users/UserName/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/99CF9C54-3B8A-47E7-8FF3-0FD688140975/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.x2AUa9/extracted/Payload/AppName.app/Frameworks/FSCalendar.framework; Extra info about Info.plist: Couldn't stat /Users/UserName/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/99CF9C54-3B8A-47E7-8FF3-0FD688140975/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.x2AUa9/extracted/Payload/AppName.app/Frameworks/FSCalendar.framework/Info.plist: No such file or directory
--
Failed to load Info.plist from bundle at path /Users/UserName/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/99CF9C54-3B8A-47E7-8FF3-0FD688140975/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.x2AUa9/extracted/Payload/AppName.app/Frameworks/FSCalendar.framework; Extra info about Info.plist: Couldn't stat /Users/UserName/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/99CF9C54-3B8A-47E7-8FF3-0FD688140975/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.x2AUa9/extracted/Payload/AppName.app/Frameworks/FSCalendar.framework/Info.plist: No such file or directory
Domain: MIInstallerErrorDomain
Code: 35
User Info: {
    FunctionName = "-[MIBundle _validateWithError:]";
    LegacyErrorString = PackageInspectionFailed;
    SourceFileLine = 131;
}
--


System Information

macOS Version 11.1 (Build 20C69)
Xcode 12.3 (17715) (Build 12C33)
```

Comment: So do you have an Info.plist file in your project?

Comment: @ElTomato It's not missing the project's Info.plist which I do have but It's saying one of the frameworks is missing Info.plist but this happened after I used Carthage update. I have checked out that project repo on GitHub but on its commit history they had not removed Info.plist.

Comment: Can you take screenshots of the path to you plist of the framework you see in target settings? and then also make sure that's exactly what you see in thee `xcodeproj` file and then make sure that the path to it matches with the actual path of the plist? Usually Xcode doesn't lie about these. Basically include enough screenshots to prove that the compiler is lying :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know what caused the problem but it seems switching to SPM solves the problem.
It is strange because everything was working just fine for the last couple of months.

Answer (score 0):

I had faced this issue on my Xcode.
Then I tried to reset content and setting of simulator and it worked for me.

Comment: I did reset content and setting of simulator but sadly it didn't work for me :((

Comment: Then please check this post and it maybe help for you.
https://handyopinion.com/solution-failed-to-load-info-plist-from-bundle-at-path-in-xcode/

Comment: I did check out that website before asking my question here but the provided solution is for cocoa pods but I am using Carthage. Thanks though for your help.

Comment: Sorry for not replying with perfect solution. I'll let you know when I get the answer.

Comment: I managed a work around. I switched to SPM for this particular framework.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226512/discussion-between-sepand-y-and-incredever).